# Unable To Drilldown With null Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

We have cases where the root level of a drilldown chart has no value but underlying categories do. When a point is null it is not rendered to the chart, which is expected. However clicking on the category label on the xAxis does not lead to the drilldown occuring. Use the basic drill [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/) and change the Animals category value to `null`. Why doesn't the xAxis label click fire the drilldown event?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are right, reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3169